# Preventing PHP to show notices for undefined arguments when using exceptions

Tags: php, notice

I think the question is fairly self-explainatory, here's the code:

> HTTP Request: localhost/execute.php?password=testing&command=create&api=api

This is part of the execution code.

```
try 
{
    $TFA_SAMP->createUser($_GET['email'], $_GET['cellphone'], $_GET['area_code']);
}
catch(Exception $createError)
{
    echo $createError->getMessage();
}
```

Here's the class method:

```
function createUser($email, $cellphone, $areaCode = 1)
{   
    if(!isset($email))
        throw new BadMethodCallException('(CTFA_SAMP->createUser) email ('. $email .') is missing.');
        
    if(!isset($cellphone))
        throw new BadMethodCallException('(CTFA_SAMP->createUser) cellphone ('. $cellphone .') is missing.');

    $authyLibrary = new Authy_Api($this->API, $this->connectionURL);
    $requestResult = $authyLibrary->registerUser($email, $cellphone, strval($areaCode));
    
    if($requestResult->ok())
    {
        echo $requestResult->id();
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($requestResult->errors() as $field => $message) 
            echo "$field = $message";
    }
}
```

The PHP pages prints:

> Notice: Undefined index: email in D:\xampp\htdocs\tfasamp\execute.php on line 46
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cellphone in D:\xampp\htdocs\tfasamp\execute.php on line 46
>
> Notice: Undefined index: area_code in D:\xampp\htdocs\tfasamp\execute.php on line 46
>
> (CTFA_SAMP->createUser) email () is missing.

How do I prevent PHP from giving me those notices as I am using exceptions to show them?

Comment: Those aren't exeptions. They're **WARNINGS**. You also shouldn't suppress/hide them: You fix the code that's generating them.

Comment: @MarcB I am aware of that, the thing is that I am using _exceptions_ to show invalid argument messages as you can see in the code.

Comment: Why do you throw these variables in exception if they are not `isset`?

Comment: You can use error_reporting(E_ERROR); in your script

Comment: Think of your code: You're checking if a variable exists. If it doesn't, you throw an execption, USING THE VARIABLE THAT YOU JUST CONFIRMED DOESN'T EXIST.  You're also checking variables that are non-optional function parameters. By definition they'd have to be set anyways for the function call to succeed.

Comment: @str That's right. I'll fix that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$TFA_SAMP->createUser($_GET['email'], $_GET['cellphone'], $_GET['area_code']);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The non-existing variables are accessed here. Nobody cares that you're *later* checking for `isset` on completely different variables and are throwing exceptions, the problem is in the above line. You need to fix it there. For example:

```
$args = $_GET + array('email' => null, 'cellphone' => null, 'area_code' => null);
$TFA_SAMP->createUser($args['email'], $args['cellphone'], $args['area_code']);
```

Alternatively, use `isset` statements here and throw exceptions for missing user input.

Basically, the code which touches `$_GET` deals with completely unpredictable user input. That's your first line of defence in which you need to check for existing or non-existing values. You can't roll this as responsibility into code which comes later.

Comment: Wouldn't `$args` be _always_ `null` in that case?

Comment: Or pass $_GET as the only arg and do all the checking within the function.